# Can't Unlock Phone Because Don't know Work Profile Password

Tags: lock-screens, profiles, samsung-galaxy-s-10, android-enterprise

I can't unlock my Samsung S10e after enabling my company's work profile. I learned [from here](http://eskonr.com/2020/11/the-case-of-unexplained-android-enterprise-work-profile-password-in-intune/) that this is because my work profile password has usurped my personal passcode for my unlock screen. Further complicating things is that I restarted my phone and everything is very locked down. Is there any way I can either remove the work profile or at least access the files on the phone before I do a factory reset?

I have tried called my company's tech support but they claim that what has happened cannot happen and when I ask them to reset the work profile password (which I never knew and none of my work passwords work), they say that they don't have that ability. They have claimed that they have revoked my phone's permissions to have a work profile, but the problem still persists. I have tried letting my phone die and then charging it back up to see if maybe it was some kind of caching issue. No dice.

Does anyone have any ideas? As long as I can recover the data on the phone I'm will to try jail breaking it or basically anything.

Edit: For clarity, this is my personal device and my company requires a work profile to use various apps with my company issued email address. That is why I enabled it when prompted.

Comment: I assume we are talking about your private device, not a company owned own. Is activating your work profile allowed in your company? Did you follow the instructions provided by your company to enable work profile on your device? If yes then your tech support is responsible. Get them the device and demand to make it work again without deleting your personal data. If there is a labor union in your company I would contact them because if the company makes your private device inaccessible this is a serious incident.

Comment: Yes this is a private device. They claim that it's not their fault and that my device manufacturer is to blame. I have even less power to do much since of course adding the work profile was an optional thing. There were no instructions really. I just followed the prompts when I saw that I had to use a work profile to access something I wanted to access on my phone. I have no union. Honestly, if I had any recourse in my company I would have taken it, but IT support is outsourced and the nature of a mega corp is I don't have direct access to many people who could help

Comment: *"They have claimed that they have revoked my phone's permissions to have a work profile"* - now your data is unrecoverable. check your [clouds](https://drive.google.com/drive/backups) for backup

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233689

Comment: Is there really no way to get at the data on the phone? I know the passcode (which is a password) to my phone on my personal profile. Is there really no way I can access the data on my phone when I know this piece of information. It feels unbelievable