# Tab A 10.1 Unknown pattern required after update

Tags: ota-update, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

System update was recently completed. After the update, the tablet now requires a pattern to sign in but one has never been used on this device. It also requires a pattern to turn off or reset so a hard reset can't be performed.

I managed a soft rest (power + vol down) but that's only made things worse as now it's not logged in to a google or samsung account so remote erasures can't be done either.

It's also won't bring up any sort of 'forgot my pattern' dialog, it just keeps showing a 30 second timer after every 'wrong' attempt. Is this a known issue? How to I get around it? I'd prefer to save my data, but a complete factory reset is still an acceptable solution.

Comment: https://thedroidguy.com/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-note-9-is-unresponsive-after-software-update-1097991 seems it is not first time such things happen https://www.androidauthority.com/samsung-galaxy-s10-unlock-problem-1008100

Comment: seems it is still not solved yet. the funny "solution" is factory reset https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S10/Phone-locked-after-last-update/td-p/730622/page/13 *"Samsung now has a special team available through the support line able to assist in getting you into the phone. They can be reached by calling 800-726-7864 and using the IVR."*